# Filling a box with color

Tags: jquery, css

When I'm pushing on the label with the class of `colorCheckBox` another div will show with a set of colors this div is called `colorSelectFilter`. Where I have a set of 3 colors. The point is to then push on a link with the different classes and add color to the label with the class of colorCheckBox

[image]

If you look at the picture you can see what I mean. 
The problem I'm having is that I need some help on how to fill the label. I have tried several things but nothing with success. Any pointers and help would be really nice. Here is my code.

```
     echo '<td><label class="colorCheckBox">';
 echo '</td>';

<div class="colorList" id="colorSelectFilter" style="display:none; padding: 20px;">
    <a href="#" data-value="1">Grön(Godkännn)<div class="greenBox"></div></a>
    <a href="#" data-value="2">Röd(Slå av)<div class="redBox"></div></a>
    <a href="#" data-value="3">Gul(Kontrollera)<div class="yellowBox"></div></a>
</div>

         $('.colorCheckBox').on('click', function(e) {
            $(".colorList").css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'left': $(this).offset().left,
        'top': $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() + 5
   }).toggle();
        });
        var colors = [];
            colors[1] = 'green';
            colors[2] = 'red';
            colors[3] = 'yellow'

 $("#colorSelectFilter").find('a').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var filter = $(this).data('value');
        // Vilken rad jag trycker på, gör det med e.target
        // Den ska få css klass beronde på vilken färg jag trycker på
        var totalColor = colors[filter];
        console.log(colors[filter] + "ErrandSelect");

        $("#errands-filter tr:not(.toptr)").each(function(){
            console.log("TEST");
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const colors = [null, 'green', 'red', 'yellow'];

$('.colorList a').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const filter = parseInt($(this).data('value'));

    if (!isNaN(filter)) {
        $('.colorCheckBox').css('background-color', colors[filter]);
    }
});
```